# Was the Starfleet officer connected to the later series?

Tags: character, star-trek, continuity, star-trek-beyond, star-trek-voyager

In *Star Trek Beyond*, we are briefly introduced to a high-ranking Starfleet officer, Commodore Paris. In the original timeline, *Voyager* had Admiral Owen Paris, and his son Tom Paris. Is Commodore Paris name meant to establish a career military family history for the Paris family? Is there any evidence that she is an ancestor of Voyager's Lieutenant J.G. Tom Paris? Much like Worf was given a TOS-era connection vía his grandfather, Colonel Worf, father of Mogh, who advocated for Kirk in *The Undiscovered Country*?

No speculation please, word of God proof only.

Answer (score 9):

Word of God: Simon Pegg - co-writer of Beyond - has said that the character is a nod to Tom Paris, and is probably his grandmother.

http://twitter.com/startrekchina/status/766502895575367680